# iPhone/iPad - table view left/right margins

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad

Is there a way to change the left/right margins on a table view? The cells seem too wide on iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and put stuff into its content view, with the frame settings that you want.